# Simulator and my iphone are not running my apps?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, simulator

I have checked multiple times in my code there are no errors or warnings. When i install it in simulator or my iphone it doesn't get past the splash screen. It just quits and doesn't say anything about crashing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using IB in your project? if so, is everything hooked up properly? also try debugging your app delegate to see how far it gets (if IB isn't the issue).

Comment: Look at the GDB console first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the crash logs for the device. After you sync it to your computer they will be stored at:

```
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>
```

Simulator crash logs are here:

```
~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/
```

They have a file extension of `.crash`

See Here:
http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/

Comment: Never mind I misspelled one view controller name, it didn't give me a warning but now it works.